# Extracting float or int number and substring from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, findall

I've just learned regex in python3 and was trying to solve a problem.
The problem is something like this:

You have given a string where the first part is a float or integer number and the next part is a substring. You must split the number and the substring and return it as a list. The substring will only contain the alphabet from a-z and A-Z. The values of numbers can be negative.
For example:

> 1. Input: 2.5ax
>    Output:['2.5','ax']
> 2. Input: -5bcf
>    Output:['-5','bcf']
> 3. Input:-69.67Gh
>    Output:['-69.67','Gh']

and so on.

I did several attempts with regex to solve the problem.

**1st attempt:**

```
import re
i=input()
print(re.findall(r'^(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)|[a-zA-Z]+$',i))
```

For the input -2.55xy, the expected output was ['-2.55','xy']
But the output came:

> [('-2.55', '.55'), ('', '')]

**2nd attempt:**
My second attempt was similar to my first attempt just a little different:

```
import re
i=input()
print(re.findall(r'^(-?(\d+\.\d+)|\d+)|[a-zA-Z]+$',i))
```

For the same input -2.55xy, the output came as:

> [('-2.55', '2.55'), ('', '')]

**3rd attempt:**
My next attempt was like that:

```
import re
i=input()
print(re.findall(r'^-?[1-9.]+|[a-z|A-Z]+$',i))
```

which matched the expected output for -2.55xy and also with the sample examples. But when the input is 2..5 or something like that, it considers that also as a float.

**4th attempt:**

```
import re
i=input()
value=re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z]+",i)
print([i.replace(value[0],""),value[0]])
```

which also matches the expected output but has the same problem as 3rd one that goes with it. Also, it doesn't look like an effective way to do it.

**Conclusion:**
So I don't know why my 1st and 2nd attempt isn't working. The output comes with a list of tuples which is maybe because of the groups but I don't know the exact reason and don't know how to solve them. Maybe I didn't understand the way the pattern works. Also why the substring didn't show in the output?
In the end, I want to know what's the mistake in my code and how can I write better and more efficient code to solve the problem. Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternation `|` matches either the left part or the right part.

If the chars a-zA-Z are after the digit, you don't need the alternation `|`  and you can use 2 capture groups to get the matches in that order.

Then using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will return a list of tuples for the capture group values.

```
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([a-zA-Z]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `-?\d+` Match an optional -
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match `.` and 1+ digits using a non capture group (so it is not outputted separately by re.findall)
- `)` Close group 1
- `(`  Capture group 2

  - `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ times a char a-z or A-Z
- `)` Close group 2

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/prmtg2/1)

```
import re

strings = [
    "2.5ax",
    "-5bcf",
    "-69.67Gh",
]

pattern = r"(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)([a-zA-Z]+)"
for s in strings:
    print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('2.5', 'ax')]
[('-5', 'bcf')]
[('-69.67', 'Gh')]
```

Comment: Ok, I understand how the capture group works but can you please explain how does **'?:'** expression works in your following pattern? Does this somehow remove **(\.\d+)** as a capture group?

Comment: @SamsilArefeen I have added an explanation about the pattern. Then `(?:` is a non capture group, so you can still make that whole part optional but as re.findall returns capture group values, the non capture group prevents that.

Answer (score 1):

lookahead and lookbehind in re.sub simplify things sometimes.

- (?<=\d) look behind
- (?=[a-zA-Z]) look ahead

that is split between the digit and the letter.

```
strings = [
    "2.5ax",
    "-5bcf",
    "-69.67Gh",
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])', s))


['2.5', 'ax']
['-5', 'bcf']
['-69.67', 'Gh']
```